# asp.net / vb - update label text

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, label

I'm having problems getting my label to update, this is the code im using..

```
Private Sub UpdateLabels(ByVal start As Date, ByVal [end] As Date, ByVal value As Double)

    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [event] WHERE NOT (([eventend] <= @start) OR ([eventstart] >= @end))", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("daypilot").ConnectionString)
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("start", start)
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("end", [end])
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("value", value)
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    da.Fill(dt)

    Dim original As DateTime = DateTime.Now ' The date you want to get the last day of the month for
    Dim lastOfMonth As DateTime = original.Date.AddDays(-(original.Day - 1)).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)

    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim startdate As Date = dt.Rows(i).Item("eventstart").ToString
            Dim enddate As Date = dt.Rows(i).Item("eventend").ToString
            Dim today As Date = Now()
            If startdate < today And enddate > today Then
                Dim add = dt.Rows(i).Item("value").ToString
                value = value + add
            ElseIf enddate <= lastOfMonth Then
                Dim add = dt.Rows(i).Item("value").ToString
                value = value + add
            End If
        Next
    End If

    If IsPostBack() Then

        LabelFMI.Text = value

        If LabelFMI.Text >= 800 = True Then
            LabelFMI.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
        Else
            LabelFMI.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
        End If

        If LabelSFA.Text >= 1000 = True Then
            LabelSFA.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
        Else
            LabelSFA.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

It is an asp:Label declard in default.aspx
Basically im trying to have this update whenever changes are made to the calendar im using - so far it works right - however the label displayed on the webpage is never updated until i close the webpage and reopen - how could i get this to update whenever changes are made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your public default class :

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        'Put here what you want to be made once
    End If

    'Put here what you what to be repeted at every postback.

End Sub
```

Comment: @Andy Does pressing F5 fix the colour (without having to close/reopen the browser)?

Comment: Nope, the page will load with thr text, ill change something that should change the text label and colour and nothing happens on refresh

Comment: cancel that, yes it has.. In fact. Just moved the code out the update sub -  is there anyway to update it without having to refresh though?